# How to prevent PowerPoint (Office 365 64-bit) window from redrawing?

Tags: vba, winapi, powerpoint

I have a graphics intense PowerPoint Add-in that is redrawing the screen. I'm trying to lock the PowerPoint window from VBA while the changes are being made with the following code (64-bit Office):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As LongPtr, Optional lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Public Const WM_SETREDRAW = &HB

Sub testLock()
    Static hWnd As LongPtr
    hWnd = FindWindow("PPTFrameClass")
    SendMessage hWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, False, 0&
End Sub

Sub testUnlock()
    Static hWnd As LongPtr
    hWnd = FindWindow("PPTFrameClass")
    SendMessage hWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, True, 0&
End Sub
```

When I do, this is the result (a mostly white window, with some stray lines):
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I tried LockWindowUpdate too and it does not prevent updates.

Comment: Not sure you're doing something "wrong" beyond playing with a window that is not yours.

Comment: Not an answer, just a thought - try double buffering. Something like this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895305/winapi-double-buffering. The cheap cheat version would be a full size window on top hiding everything while drawing.

Comment: @sam This doesn't change the core issue: You cannot render onto a window you do not own, and hope for any particular result. If you need a device context to render into, you'll need to create (and own) a window.

Comment: @SimonMourier Sounds like this isn't possible then. The sample LockWindowUpdate code looked simple enough that I thought it would be easy to drop in. When it didn't work, I tried SendMessage and it didn't work either. I'm not even sure yet that I really need to lock the window. I will either live with it as-is, or experiment with popping up an in-progress window over the top, but at least I know to stop trying to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: You're still failing to acknowledge the core issue here: You cannot draw onto a window you do not own. The result is ephemeral. Whenever the window decides that it's time to render its contents, anything you put there will be gone (say, because part of the window gets uncovered as a result of minimizing another window that previous obscured it). If you need your drawing to persist, you will need to create your own window.

Comment: @IInspectable Understood. I’ve given up on using LockWindowUpdate and SendMessage. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: It's generally possible to open a PPT/PPTX windowlessly and perform whatever operations on it you like; everything you do to the windowless presentation will be invisible.