# Any suggestions to effectively update the status bar of an application?

Tags: winapi

The status bar window of this program needs to be updated every time the user press a key that is likely to move the caret of the EDIT control, and the code below works like a charm! In a nutshell, pressing a key on the keyboard will update some values and send a message "ECM_GETLINEINFOS" that is next processed in the main window procedure (code below)

However, there is flickering that is not disturbing, of course, but I wonder if it's related to how I set the text on the status bar (maybe too many updates ?) or just a problem with the drawing part.

*PS: The flickering occurs on the text, not the status bar in itself, so that is why I'm questioning how I should manage the update of my window.*

```cpp
constexpr int failed_val = -1;

LRESULT MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        // Custom message sent by an EDIT control, I 
        // use this message to tell the status bar it must update its text.
        case CEM_GETLINEINFO: 
        {
            const size_t buffSz = 24;
            std::wstring buffer(buffSz, L'\0');
            int line = LOWORD(wParam);
            int column = HIWORD(wParam);

            int count = _snwprintf_s(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 
            _TRUNCATE, L"Ln %d, Col %d", line, column);
            
            if (count != failed_val) {
                // Param 1 : The text to be displayed
                // Param 2 : Which status bar part
                m_statusBar->SetText(buffer, 0);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. What you should do is get the current text at that item and only set the text if it is different than what it is currently set to. I don't do MFC anymore but there was some API like `AfxSetWindowText()` or something like that that I remember from back in the day. If you only update when it needs to change, the flicker will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, I use the RAW WinAPI but encapsulated, so MFC can't be used. The window doesn't need to check whether the text needs to be changed or not, bc these lines are not executed until the user press a key (which means that the text at part 0 needs to be updated). The first step is done! the flicker is indeed not very noticeable. Maybe it's also a problem with the message queue (too slow to process, and the painting occurs only when all other messages are processed according to Microsoft's website unless UpdateWindow() is called and the selected zone is invalidated)

Answer (score 1):

Just as [Flicker-Free Displays Using an Off-Screen DC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms969905(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#a-control-that-flickers) directed by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3896242/15511041) said,

> What makes this window flicker when we update it frequently? The
> answer is that Windows asks the window procedure to repaint the window
> as a two-step process. First, it sends a WM_ERASEBKGND message and
> then a WM_PAINT message. The default handling for the WM_ERASEBKGND
> message is to fill the area with the current window background color.
> So the sequence of events is first to fill the area with solid color
> and then to draw the text on top. The net result of doing this
> frequently is that the window state alternates between its erased
> state and its drawn state—it flickers.

And

> To prevent the control from flickering when we update it frequently,
> we need to make two changes to how the control handles messages.
> First, we need to prevent Windows from providing the default handling
> of WM_ERASEBKGND messages. Secondly, we need to handle WM_PAINT
> messages so that the background is painted with the window background
> color and so that the changes to the control's client area happen at
> once.

A status bar flicker free solution in .NET: Searching *Visual Studio .NET style status bar*. Or [Simple Mode Status Bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bars#simple-mode-status-bars) could be enough.